# Compiling cvblob on OSX does not correctly locate OpenCV libs

Tags: macos, opencv, cmake

I'm having issues with CVBlob locating the OpenCV installation on OSX 10.6.  I have patch for the osx install as described in an earlier message on the cvblob wiki.  When I run make, the build process immediately complains that it cannot find cv.h or highgui.h and then subsequently fails to locate additional symbols and vars declared in those headers.

The cmake command I am using is :
cmake -DOpenCV_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.3.1a/ .

I can see that cv.h is contained in the includes directory in that location.  I also tried the following cmake command where I specify the location of the OpenCV Cmake info:

cmake -DOpenCV_DIR=/usr/local/share/OpenCV/ .

Neither seems to correctly tell the cvblob installation where OpenCV is located.

Please help!

SR

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of cvBlob, openCV is automatically located. But version 0.10.4 and before expects the openCV directory to be located **next to** the cvblob directory. Specifically, version 0.10.4 seems to expect the `opencv-2.4.9` directory to be next to `cvblob`. In this version of cvBlob, the `-DOpenCV_DIR` parameter seems to have no effect on OS X, and this was the only way I could get it working.

Answer (score -1):

Are you working with Xcode?

If so, just add the OpenCV-path to your header search path in your Xcode project.